# How does an object access the symbol table for the current package?

Tags: perl, symbol-table

How could I access the symbol table for the current package an object was instantiated in? For example, I have something like this:

```
my $object = MyModule->new;
# this looks in the current package, to see if there's a function named run_me
# I'd like to know how to do this without passing a sub reference
$object->do_your_job;
```

If in the implementation of `do_your_job` I use `__PACKAGE__`, it will search in the `MyModule` package. How could I make it look in the right package?

EDIT:I'll try to make this clearer. Suppose I have the following code:

```
package MyMod;

sub new {
    return bless {},$_[0]
}

sub do_your_job {
    my $self = shift;
    # of course find_package_of is fictional here
    # just for this example's sake, $pkg should be main
    my $pkg = find_package_of($self);
    if(defined &{ $pkg . '::run_me' }) {
        # the function exists, call it.
    }
}

package main;

sub run_me {
   print "x should run me.\n";
}

my $x = MyMod->new;

# this should find the run_me sub in the current package and invoke it.
$x->do_your_job;
```

Now, `$x` should somehow notice that `main` is the current package, and search it's symbol table. I tried using `Scalar::Util`'s blessed , but it still gave me `MyModule` instead of `main`. Hopefully, this is a bit clearer now.

Comment: When confronted by a problem like this, one of the first places I turn is the Perl Functions by Category section of perlfunc. It has nicely grouped lists of built-ins that make it easy to skim for things that might be related to the issue at hand.  In this case the section labeled "Keywords related to scoping" has 8 items to check.  The first is `caller`.  
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#Perl-Functions-by-Category

Comment: Now that we've established what the right answer is I'm curious to know why you want to do this. Having a method access the symbol table for the package that instantiated an object strikes me as a Very Bad Idea under the vast majority of circumstances.

Comment: I saw this tutorial http://search.cpan.org/~ROBERTMAY/Win32-GUI/docs/GUI/Tutorial/Part1.pod for Win32::GUI , and I imagined this was how the `Main_Terminate` was implemented.

Comment: @Geo: You might be right. (In spirit, at least; Win32::GUI is primarily XS code.) I've always hated GUI toolkits that rely on naming conventions to implement callbacks.

Comment: I wanted to know how it was done ... knowing what made it work seemed pretty interesting. And it is :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just want [`caller`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#caller)

`caller` tells you the package from which it was called. (Here I added some standard perl.)

```
use Symbol qw<qualify_to_ref>;
#...
my $pkg = caller;

my $symb   = qualify_to_ref( 'run_me', $pkg );
my $run_me = *{$symb}{CODE};
$run_me->() if defined $run_me;
```

To look it up and see if it's defined and then look it up to call it would duplicate it as standard perl doesn't do Common Subexpression Elimination, so you might as well 1) retrieve it, and 2) check definedness of the slot, and 3) run it if it is defined.

Now if you create an object in one package and use it in another, that's not going to be too much help. You would probably need to add an additional field like `'owning_package'` in the constructor.

```
package MyMod;

#...
sub new { 
    #...
    $self->{owning_package} = caller || 'main';
    #...
}
```

Now `$x->{owning_package}` will contain `'main'`.

Comment: Funny Sinan :) ! I think it's obvious this was what I wanted from the first time.

Comment: @Geo Well, it is a good thing the edit history is available then. I mean, three otherwise reasonable people misunderstood what you were asking and you had to clarify.

Comment: It's why I added the extra clarification. I noticed it wasn't what I was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

See [perldoc -f caller](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package A;
use strict; use warnings;

sub do_your_job {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my ($pkg) = caller;
    if ( my $sub = $pkg->can('run_me') ) {
        $sub->();
    }
}

package B;
use strict; use warnings;

sub test {
    A->do_your_job;
}

sub run_me {
    print "No, you can't!\n";
}

package main;

use strict; use warnings;

B->test;
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> h
No, you can't!
```